# Encoding & decoding custom Swift objects with recursive pointers

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, nscoder, state-restoration

I'm trying to encode and decode an array of custom objects in swift. The objects look something like this:

```
class MyObject : NSCoding {
  var name: String
  var otherObjects: [MyObject]

  init?(name: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.otherObjects = []
  }

  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(otherObjects, forKey: "others")
  }

  required convenience public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    let others = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "others") as! [MyObject]

    self.init(name: name)
    self.otherObjects = others
  }
}
```

If MyObject A contains MyObject B in its array, B will also have A in its array. The trouble is, as implemented above, this fails during startup, unable to perform this recursive decoding. Stepping through with the debugger, it looks like

1. The app tries to decode A
2. In decoding A, it must decode A's `others` array, which contains B
3. The app must now decode B. In doing so, it sees that A is in B's `others` array.
4. The app starts to decode A (the A pointed to by B's encoded representation), and fails when trying to do so.

It seems like with this approach I'm not preserving the original state (i.e. after decoding, A and B point not to each other but to copies of each other). What's the recommended way to encode and decode a data structure like mine with NSCoder?

Comment: *something like this* does not compile.

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver can handle circular references – a [mcve] would be helpful.